# How do I use mocha and chai with legacy javascript project and not get the "cannot find module" error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I'm adding unit tests to a legacy php project that has a lot of older javascript classes. Specially I'm trying to write tests on a file that is located in ./public/scripts/ directory.

The Javascript looks like it's es4 or 5.

I've added npm package.json babel, mocah, and chai to the project.

I keep getting the following error when I run tests.
`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '~/Development/web/OHB/dev/public/script/world' imported from ~/Development/web/OHB/dev/tests/js/world.test.js`

My package.json looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "ohb",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./public/script/main.js",
  "description": "package management for the javascript application that configures the building configurator",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npx mocha \"./tests/js/*.test.js\" --recursive --require @babel/register"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.15.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "mocha": "^9.1.2"
  }
}
```

The javascript file I'm trying to test is in /public/scripts/world.js and looks like this.

```
    import * as THREE from "../../../build/three.module.js";
    import {OHBBuilding, focuspoint} from "/script/bap/building.js";
    import {OrbitControls} from "/assets/js/OrbitControls.js";

    export var container;
    export var camera, scene, renderer;
    export var groundMaterial, barn, controls;
    export var loaded3d = false;
    var canexpand=true;
    var builder;

    export var objects = [], plane;
    var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
    SELECTED= new THREE.Vector3();

    function myTestFunction() {
        return {};
    }


///lots of other functions below here

    module.exports = { myTestFunction };
```

my test looks like this

```
import { expect } from "chai";
import { myTestFunction } from "../../public/script/world";

describe('myTestFunction - does it return an object', () => {
    it('returns an empty object', () => {


        const expected = {};
        const actual = myTestFunction();
        expect(expected).to.deep.equal(actual);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this one is a little tricky, so let me split that into two parts:

### 1. ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND

There's an message that the module cannot be found, because you haven't specified the extension. If you replace second line in your test to:

```js
import { myTestFunction } from "../../public/script/world.js";
```

the module will be found. It's happening because node.js does not infer the file extension. This can be easily changed by adding an argument `--es-module-specifier-resolution=node` to your mocha command:

```sh
npx mocha \"./tests/js/*.test.js\" --recursive --require @babel/register --es-module-specifier-resolution=node
```

There's node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_customizing_esm_specifier_resolution_algorithm) about it, although it's quite a long read.

### 2. ReferenceError

After you've got your `world.js` file visible from the test file you'll get another error:

```sh
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/root/stack-overflow/mocha-help/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

You've got two ways of dealing with that:

1. You need to rewrite export in `world.js` file to the new ES module syntax:

```
export { myTestFunction };
```

2. You can rename the file to `world.cjs` and refer to that extension in the test file.

There's really no difference in both, so it boils down to which option will be easier to implement.